# diff does not contain new files

Tags: git, diff, git-index

I am working on a project which uses git. Whenever I make changes, I submit a patch to the main developer who apply and commit it. Things worked nicely this far whith:

```
git diff > somepatch.patch
```

But when I create new files, The above command doesn't work. It creates a patch which doesn't contain new files that I created. I tried adding them to git like this:-

```
git add path/to/the/file.qml
```

but this also doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already added your changes to the repo, they won't appear in the `git diff` output unless you use the `--staged` parameter to ask for changes already added to index.

```
git diff --staged > your.patch
```

So if you have a mix of added and non-yet-added changes, you can even the situation with

```
git add .
```

then proceed with your diff.

---

As a sidenote, an alternative would be to unstage everything and do a classic diff without `--staged` :

```
git reset HEAD
git diff > your.patch
```

Comment: now it is only showing the file that I added. Its not showing the changes that I made in other file

Comment: @yojimbooru Add everything beforehand with `git add .` then all should be featured in `git diff --staged` output.

Comment: To add a bit to this (correct) answer, note that `git diff` without `--staged` tells Git: *compare the files stored in my index to the files stored in my work-tree*. If there is no difference, your index and work-tree match. But *with* `--staged`, you are telling Git: *compare the files stored in my `HEAD` commit to the files stored in my index*. Your work-tree is completely ignored for this `--staged` diff! There are *three* copies of every file: one in `HEAD` (frozen), one in index ("slushy": in Git format, but not quite frozen so you can change it), and one in your work-tree.